# How do I make a link from a PDF?

Tags: pdf, hyperlink

I'm doing a project and I need the table of contents to have links so I can be brought to different parts of the same document with this. I know how to make a link in the program I'm using (google docs) but I'm not sure where I find the link to another page in the PDF. I know how to do this on Adobe but I don't have access to the Pro portion of Adobe. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

- Select the word or phrase you want to be hyperlinked.
  Go to insert link button. Write the destination URL, click Ok.

  [image]

Comment: Thank you but that wasn't quite what I meant. I know how to do that, my problem is getting the URL. This is an example of my goal: (this site) https://www.marinetech.org/files/marine/files/ROV%20Competition/2017%20competition/2017%20Technical%20Documentation/EXPLORER%20class/BMSTU_Hydronautics_Technical_Report_2017.pdf If you look at the table of contents, you'll see how if you click on the topics it brings you to another page. So how do I get the URL for those other pages?